# Какую команду передать firefox для обновления окна(вкладки)?

Tags: bash, firefox, консоль, браузер

Хотелось бы назначить горячую клавишу на обновления вкладки браузера, дабы обновлять даже его окно не активно. 
ОС Ubuntu

Comment: vimperator случайно не умеет такого?

Comment: А, вы, наверное, хотите вообще из командной строки? Смотрите как это делают тестовые фреймворки типа Selenium.